# How to iterate through a list and create a custom non-sequential output

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to compare lines of two separate files and output the result (saved into a separate List) in a specific manner. 
File1 is the original text. File2 either has some of the same lines or new lines. Meaning that some lines that are present in File1 are missing in File2.

For example:
 
**File1**:
A
B
C
D
E

**File2**:
B
C
D
F
G

Output of the combined list before custom sort:
A - Removed
B - Same
C - Same
D - Same
E - Removed
F - New
G - New

What I need to do is output the list in the following manner:
A - Removed
B - Same
E - Removed
C - Same
F - New
D - Same
G - New

Basically, the lines that are the same need to be shown (or saved initially?) on every second index.

I have so far managed to compare the files (by adding lines from each file to two separate linked lists and comparing them) and created a combined List with a line status (i.e. same, removed, new) added to each line.
However, I just can't get my head round the algorithm for this kind of custom sort, as I am new to Java.
Do I need to create a custom Iterator and pass it to my combined List? Or can this be achieved with the default listIterator?

Code so far:

```
public class Solution {
    public static List<LineItem> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (BufferedReader fileOne = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
             BufferedReader fileTwo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"))) {

            List<String> listOne = new LinkedList<>();
            List<String> listTwo = new LinkedList<>();
            List<LineItem> listOfSame = new LinkedList<>();
            List<LineItem> result = new ArrayList<>();

            String line;

            while ((line = fileOne.readLine()) != null) {
                listOne.add(line);
            }

            while ((line = fileTwo.readLine()) != null) {
                listTwo.add(line);
            }

            for (String s : listOne) {
                if (listTwo.contains(s)) {
                    listOfSame.add(new LineItem(Type.SAME, s));
                } else if (!listTwo.contains(s)) {
                    lines.add(new LineItem(Type.REMOVED, s));
                }
            }

            for (String s : listTwo) {
                if (!listOne.contains(s)) {
                    lines.add(new LineItem(Type.ADDED, s));
                }
            }


            Iterator<LineItem> itSame = listOfSame.iterator();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                result.add(lines.get(i));

                if (i % 2 == 0 && itSame.hasNext()) {
                   result.add(itSame.next());
                }
            }

            while (itSame.hasNext()) {
                result.add(itSame.next());
            }

            for (LineItem item : result) {
              System.out.println(item.type.toString() + " " + item.line);                
            }


        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

    public static enum Type {
        ADDED,        // New line added
        REMOVED,      // Line deleted
        SAME          // No change
    }

    public static class LineItem {
        public Type type;
        public String line;

        public LineItem(Type type, String line) {
            this.type = type;
            this.line = line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code!

Comment: Sorry, now added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could move the `SAME` items into a separate list and then go through both lists and output a `SAME` line every other iteration (doing a pseudo [merge sort](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-sort)). Something like:

```
List<LineItem> sameOnes = new ArrayList();
Iterator<LineItem> it = lines.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  LineItem item = it.next();
  if (item.type == Type.SAME) {
    sameOnes.add(item);
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

And then:

```
List<LineItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<LineItem> sameIt = sameOnes.iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
  result.add(lines.get(i));
  // Ensure there still are same lines to output
  if (sameIt.hasNext()) {
    result.add(sameIt.next());
  }
}
// Fill in the rest in case there were more same than different lines
while (sameIt.hasNext()) {
  result.add(sameIt.next());
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it gives me the following output:
Removed
Removed
Same
Added
Added
Same
Same

Comment: I edited the if to say i % 2 == 0 and the output looks like this: 1) Removed 2) Same 3) Removed 4) Added 5) Same 6) Added 7) Same. 
Not sure why number 4 is not Same, as it should be. If I take away the last while loop then the 7) Same goes missing too. I've edited my code above.

Comment: Aww, shoot. You're right. There shouldn't have been any modulo 2, that way, a `SAME` line would be only once in three lines. I've edited the solution. Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I tweaked your solution and added the sameOnes and result lists at the top and then added the Same lines to the sameOnes list right in the first for loop, when comparing both files. This meant that I did not need the first part of your solution any longer.